# Issues with the Virtual Box installation

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, virtualization, mininet

I am trying to configure mininet on the  virtual box version VirtualBox 5.1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 ("Trusty") -  AMD64 native machine.

facing the following issues:

[screen shot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paaGU.png)

[Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd2cx.png)

Log file from terminal: vi /var/log/vbox-install.log